# Different approaches to a convergence criterion

Tags: general-topology

Consider sequences $x_n = \{x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\cdots\}$ converge pointwisely to a limit $x = \{x_{\infty,1},x_{\infty,2},\cdots\}$ which is a convergent sequence itself, i.e.
$x_{\infty,n} \to \tilde{x}$.

We can formulate an equivalent statement as follows,
the sequence converges iff
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} d (x_{n,i},x_{\infty,i})2^{-i}\to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty,$$
given that $d(x,y)\leq 1$ for all $x,y$.

It can be proved by dominated convergence theorem and a term from the summation of nonnegative terms is smaller than the summation.

However I have seen the argument that it is the metric of product topology.
How does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. How to show that that metric induces the product topology?

Comment: @DanielFischer I want to know the details of how it formulate a metric in product topology and hence it gives an equivalent statement of convergence.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @newbie "the sequence converges" refers to the sequence $x$ of point wise limits?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space with a metric bounded, say, by $1$, then the space of all sequences on $X$, $X^\mathbb{N}$, in the product topology (a.k.a. the topology of pointwise convergence) is metrizable with product metric $d_{\infty}((x_i)_i,(y_i)_i) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^i} d(x_i, y_i)$.

In a metric space $(Y, d)$ a sequence $(y_n)_n$ converges to $y$ iff $d(y_n , y) \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Combining these two facts yields: a sequence of sequences $x_n = (x_{n,i})$ converges to $x = (x_{\infty,i})$ pointwisely iff $\sum_i \frac{1}{2^i} d(x_{n,i},x_{\infty,i}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. There is no need to assume $x$ itself is a convergent sequence, unless you are working in the subspace of $X^\mathbb{N}$ of convergent sequences (which has the same inherited metric).

Comment: I also think that the doundedness of metric may be removed, since $1\wedge d$ and $\frac{d}{1+d}$ are topologically equivalent to $d$. Is that correct?

Comment: @newbie Yes, but you mentioned it in your question. We can replace the original metric by the bounded one, but then the convergence of the sum is indeed done in the bounded version, not the original one.